# Make a Progress Counter in Concurrent Python

Tags: python

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

alreadyProcessedFile = 0.0
processLength = 0.0

def convertedFile(filePath):

    fileName = os.path.basename(filePath).split('.')[0]

    print("Total: "+str(processLength)+", current: "+str(alreadyProcessedFile)
          + ", percentage: "+ str((alreadyProcessedFile+1.0)/(processLength+1)))

    #business logic

    print("One file is saved at the location: "+r'E:\xxx\SECProject\ProcessedSEC10KFiles\2012QTR1/'+fileName+'-finalDoc.txt')

def getFilePath(path):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = r"E:\xxx\SECProject\SEC10KFiles\2012QTR1"
    fileList = getFilePath(s)
    processLength = len(fileList)
    p = Pool(40)
    p.map(convertedFile, fileList)
```

This is basically a shortened version of the python program. I don't have a wrapper class outside and I want to have a counter inside to keep track of the progress (so I know when the program will stop). However the program (`def covertedFile()` have a problem accessing the changed variables: `alreadyProcessedFile` and `processLength`)

I know concurrency might have problems with shared state, but how can you accomplish a counter without some degree of shared state?? And why can't the concurrent function access the variable outside of it?

---

Also as weird as it may sound, this concurrent version program can't process all files (about 5000 of them) under one directory. I wonder if the program is shut down while some processes are still running. Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multiprocessing` creates a *copy* of the memory for each process at the time you start the new processes.  Sharing state via module-level globals doesn't work because every process gets it's own "snapshot" of the globals at the time you fork the process.  Changing one processes' globals doesn't magically propagate to other processes.

If you need to share state between processes, you need to use one of the tools that `multiprocessing` gives to you.  You can share c types via `Value` or `Array`, or use `Manager` to share arbitrary data types.  See [sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) in the docs for details and examples.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't use a `Process` but a `Pool`, so how do you pass in extra parameter with a `Pool` construction?